# db2 restore database and privileges

Tags: db2, restore, privileges

I have a backup of database (IBM DB2 v. 9.7)

After restore command I cannot access some of the tables due to privileges issues. 
On the original db client and database we have a user: userx with admin privileges and on the new db client we have a usery also with admin privileges.

restore is done but I cannot access the database tables

Can somebody explain me what is the problem

thank you

Answer (score 0):

In version 9.7, authorities like DBADM do not have data access privilege, because of the separation of duties. This is granted via SECADM.

Check the authorizations via the authorizations view: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022658.html

Check the priviles granted to "userX" and mimic those privileges to "usery".